# ¿Como mostrar solo una parte de una cadena en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla y en esta, una columna de correos. Lo que necesito es que mediante una consulta solo se muestre los dominios, es decir `hotmail.com`, `gmail.com`, etc..

```
SELECT  correo FROM cliente
```

Answer (score 3):

Podemos aprovechar el `@` como caracter separador, y quedarnos con la palabra a derecha del mismo. Lo podríamos hacer así:

```
DECLARE @correo  VARCHAR(255)
SELECT  @correo = 'Jose@mail.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@correo, CHARINDEX('@', @correo)+1,LEN(@correo))

----------
"mail.com"
```

Buscamos con [`CHARINDEX()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) la posición de `@` y recortamos desde ese lugar + 1 hasta el fin de la cadena con [`SUBSTRING()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql). Llevandolo a tu ejemplo sería:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(correo, CHARINDEX('@', correo)+1,LEN(correo))
        FROM cliente
```